# Null pointer exception in for loop with random numbers

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

For some reason my code gives one random number but crashes after the second due to a null pointer exception. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

```
public void shownumbers() {
    Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
        MyTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Random r = new Random();
                TextView viewbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                viewbox.setText(Integer.toString(r.nextInt(10)));
            }
        }, 100, 500);
```

Comment: Please share your logcat

Comment: @EdGeorge not really a duplicate because context here is quite relevant.

Comment: In short, at some point you are ending up with `null.member` where `member` is field or method. But `null` doesn't have any members. You need to check your log to and debut what exactly is your `null`.

Comment: The issue is probably that you are calling `setText` on the wrong thread. Use `runOnUiThread` to ensure you are doing it on the UI Thread

Comment: Thanks! I had to use runOnUikThread!

Answer (score 0):

The function [`findViewById(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) returns `null` if `R.id.textView` is not found. You can check the stack trace of your `NullPointerException` and find the exact line where it fails.